# Is there any method to calculate the distance between two phylogenetic trees in BioPython?

Tags: python, tree, bioinformatics, biopython, phylogeny

I'm using BioPython to generate phylogenetic trees. Now I want to calculate the distance between two trees using a method such as "Robinson-Foulds Distances". Is there any method to calculate the distance between two phylogenetic trees in BioPython? I have gone through the documentation and I couldn't find any method.

Comment: No I don't think there is. You could raise a feature request on Biopython github, but or else use another tool like iqtree http://www.iqtree.org/doc/Command-Reference

Comment: Be aware of the shortcomings of the Robinson–Foulds distance. More sophisticated tree distance measures are implemented in the R package "TreeDist": https://ms609.github.io/TreeDist/